# Django начало urls.py (rango)

Tags: python, django

Делаю пример по книге "танго с джанго"
создал проект, запустил и создал приложение **rango** командой 
`python manage.py startapp rango`.

Добавил `rango` в INSTALLED_APPS.

Создал views в подкаталоге rango с кодом:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rango says hey there partner!")
```

Далее по книжке нужно внести изменения в файл основного проекта urls.py:

```
from rango import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

[image: скриншот компиляции и кода программы]

выдаёт ошибку, подскажите в чем проблема

Comment: Уберите решетку перед двумя строками импорта, уберите точку перед `rango`.

Comment: убрал, вот что пишет 
No module named 'rango', хотя в инстал аппс он у меня добавлен

Comment: А зачем вы запускаете файлик `urls.py`? Надо в корне запустить manage.py с параметром runserver: `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Как для чего? Я знаю, что я должен manage.py запускать, но толку если тут при компиляции ошибки? Ну запустил я сервер, он запустился с ошибками

Comment: Python не компилируемый язык, а интерпретируемый. Разбирайте ошибки в консоли сервера, простой запуск отдельных файлов ничего не даст.

Comment: Да, вы правы, ну вот запустил просто на сервере и изменения, вот что выдало








      Using the URLconf defined in yres_tango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this 
      order:

admin/
^$ [name='index']
The empty path didn't match any of these.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86319/discussion-between-ug45-and-floydya).

Answer (score 0):

все заработало) изменил строчку в файл urls.py 
с

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

на

```
 path('', admin.site.urls),
```